# How could I change WatchService to the stream api

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I have code which is monitoring the directory via `WatchService` in Java.
But currently I am using loops, but I would like to change it to streams.

```
try {
            WatchService watchService = FileSystems.getDefault().newWatchService();

            Paths.get(dirPath).register(watchService, StandardWatchEventKinds.ENTRY_CREATE);
            WatchKey key;
            while ((key = watchService.take()) != null) {
                for (WatchEvent<?> event : key.pollEvents()) {

                    String fileName = event.context().toString();
                    if (isPdfFile(fileName)) {
                        runOnOption.get(option).accept(dirFilePath);
                        return;
                    }
                }
                key.reset();
            }
        }
        catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {}
    }
```

Method `isPdfFile` check if the file is pdf and if yes, it is going to rename and create log file for renaming. 
So what I was able to do is:

```
    key.pollEvents()
       .stream()
       .filter(e -> isEdxFile(e.context().toString()))
       .forEach( e -> runOnOption.get(option).accept(dirPath+e.context().toString()));
```

But what I am missing is while loop and return from loop when it will find file with pdf extension.

Answer (score 2):

What you might be looking for is

```
.findFirst() // first element with such a filter condition
.ifPresent(e -> runOnOption.get(option).accept(dirPath+e.context().toString()));
```

to return as soon as such an element is found after performing the consumer logic.

Comment: It might work only if we got foreach loop without while loop. Because I need to call return when the condition is meet otherwise loop will go infinitly.

Comment: @Suule so you want to exit the `while` loop as well if such condition is met? and would executing the `key.reset()` do that for you?

Comment: No, `key.reset()` is making `WatchKey` able to monitor for events again. So every loop where event is detected we need to reset key again. From what I did, only `return`  was able to stop monitoring dir.

Comment: *only return was able to stop monitoring dir* .. but that's what you do until you find the first element with the mentioned filter.. right?

Comment: Yes, but in case of my code without stream. `return` was quitting method. In stream I think when you `findFirst` you are quitting only stream not whole function. And than on new event you are entering stream again.